# Converting a file with ".dotx" extension (template) to "docx" (Word File)

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

How to convert a ".dotx" Word template to a plain ".docx" using a  POI APIs or Docx4j?

Comment: Add some code that you have tried. so, we can help you.

Comment: What happens when you change the file extension from .dotx to .docx?

Comment: For docx4j, please see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/docx4j/org/docx4j/samples/TemplateAttach.java#L57

Comment: Because someone voted the comment "What happens when you change the file extension from .dotx to .docx? " as useful: The answer is simply that Word then will not opening that `*.docx` file then. The `*.dotx` and `*.docx` have different content types which are not magically changed when file extension in file name is changed.

Comment: A typically Stackoverflow closing action here. Four of the five closing voters not having any experience using `apache poi` and/or `docx4j` but vote closing a question about it. Why? Because the question cannot be answered? No, it really could be answered (see my answer and the comment of @JasonPlutext. But the question is short and do not contains some code. But why should it be more verbose? And how should it contain code the questioner don't knows and that's why he asks for?

Comment: @JasonPlutext actually the methode cloneAs() is not working , i get this message 'The method cloneAs(String) is undefined for the type WordprocessingMLPackage' do you have any suggestions, thank you .

Comment: [public OpcPackage cloneAs(String targetContentType)](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/packages/OpcPackage.java#L960) : "@since 6.1.0".

Comment: @AxelRichter Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The need is changing the content type of `/word/document.xml` from `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template.main+xml` to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml`.

Example using `apache poi 4.0.1`:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class WordReadDOTXSaveDOCX {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("StudentReport.dotx"));
  document.getPackage().replaceContentType(
   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template.main+xml",
   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml");

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("TheDocumentFromDOTXTemplate.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: Hello Axel Richter, I Hope you're fine, sorry for being late , i just try this code today but i get a docx file with a message error 'The file cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents' , thanks for the help.

Comment: @youssef elhayani: This code is tested and works for me using `apache poi 4.0.1`. If it does not work for you, please refine your question. Show the exact code which does not wor for you. Tell us `apache poi`version you are using. Provide an example `*.dotx` file using which it does not work.

Comment: accually i used apache poi 3.13 and i used the same come that you did. there the dependency :
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.13</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: I will try apache poi 4.0.1 and see if it work

Comment: Thank You !! it's Working , it's all about the version of apache POI !

Comment: Hi guys, I am looking for a .dot file reading example and I stumbled upon this stackoverflow answer. I know it is for .dotx but it doesn't work for .dot, or at least I couldn't figure it out on my own, can you help me?

Comment: If you do not use any library this needs to be chnaged inside "[Content_Types].xml"