# Converting a file with “.dotx” extension (template) to “docx” (Word File) not working in window 10 and window server 2016

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx

I'm trying to convert a dotx file to docx file using this programme [Converting a file with ".dotx" extension (template) to "docx" (Word File)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377200/converting-a-file-with-dotx-extension-template-to-docx-word-file), it's working in Window 7 but when i try to run it in window 10 or windows server 2016, i get this error :

[image]

Please, If there is any suggestion, do not hesitate.

Thank You !

PS: I'm using Office 2013.

Comment: Your question is not clear. My code works using `apache poi 4.0.1` which in my case runs using `Java 8`. This should not be dependent on different operating systems. So the question is does your `Windows 7` system, using which it works, using another `apache poi` and/or `java` version than your `Windows 10` or `Windows Server 2016` system.

Comment: @Axel Richter does apach POI depend on the Java version ?

Comment: It should not. But maybe? It is my only suspicion to explain your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the POI documentation, I figure out that there is a correlation between the 
POI version and JDK Version,I thought that the problem is in the operation system but it's not true, in other Machine i was using JDK 1.7 with apache POI 4.0.1.
The Right combination is :

**POI 4.0 and later require JDK version 1.8 or later.**

**POI 3.11 and later 3.x versions require JDK version 1.6 or later.**

**POI 3.5 to 3.10 required the JDK version 1.5 or later. Versions prior to 3.5 required JDK 1.4+.**

see more in https://poi.apache.org/devel/index.html